# Close all WPF windows from winforms application

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, window

I host a WPF application in my winforms application via the `ElementHost` control. I've implemented a logic which listens to unhandled exceptions on WPF side. If an exception is catched, the `ElementHost` control should be disposed and all related WPF windows should be closed.

This works quite fine, if there is only one WPF window. Since that WPF application can open up more sub windows (which are undocked windows) those windows are not closed when I dispose the `ElementHost` control.

Is there an easy way to close that WPF window and all child windows from winforms side?

I have tried `Application.OpenForms` but the sub WPF windows do not show up (makes sense somehow ;-)).

**One remark**: I do own the WPF code so I could implement something on the WPF side, but I really would like to stick on the win forms side.

Also I would like to consider situations where the WPF window code might be "stuck" and is not able to react and close it self. That's why I'd like to kill the windows from "outside"

Comment: Well, keep your own `List<Window>` around.  Add the window when you create the WPF window, remove it with the window's Closed event.

Comment: Shouldn't the WPF window have the responsibility of cleaning up its children when closing?

Comment: @HansPassant I do not have problems finding that root WPF window (since its hosted in the `ElementHost`)

Comment: @cdkMoose I basically would agree with you, but I was thinking about a situation where the WPF windows might not be able to react and are somehow "stuck". Then I would like to be able to kill the windows

Comment: Not sure I can imagine a scenario where the WPF window that created the children couldn't kill them, but the WinForms window could.  Do you have a use case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I made up my mind and followed cdkMoose recommendation to let this be handled by the WPF part. It's probably a good idea to let the clean up be done by the one who has the knowledge about what has to be done. Thanks though!

Comment: Just to add... The "Getting stuck" thing you mention is best handled using a separate AppDomain. You can destroy/recreate AppDomains without impacting your main code. Note that while a 2nd AppDomain could open a new window, it will will be challenging to have a control from one domain rendered in another's window (you'd need to emulate the basics of the window manager)